# Why is b always null?

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to set a value on a defined property in a sub class.

```
export class Parent {

    protected a: number = null;

    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        this.a = 1;
    }
}
```

```
import {Parent} from './Parent';

export class Child extends Parent {

    protected b: number = null;

    init(){
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
    }


    getB(){
        return [this.a, this.b];
    }
}
```

```
import {Child} from './Child';
var c = new Child();
console.log(c.getB());
```

`getB()` returns `[1, null]`, why doesn't the value get set?

Comment: The problem is the same as described there, it has to do with the order in which `init` and the field initialization are executed. If you feel the duplicate does not answer I can reopen the question, but the answer would be pretty much the same

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir isnt it the lack of `super()` and a derived class constructor?

Comment: @Jamiec No, the compiler will create a constructor for the class call super and the assign the fields in in if you don't explicitly create a constructor